# How to use existing Constrains autolayout when moving sabview up?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, autolayout

i am showing and hiding subview from bottom----->top or top ---->Bottom with **UIViewAnimation** using below code

```
-(IBAction)showClander
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];
    pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568-368, pickerView.frame.size.width, pickerView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)hideClander
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];
    pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, pickerView.frame.origin.y+368, pickerView.frame.size.width, pickerView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The above code working fine when i did not using Autolayout ,but because my app supporting both portrait and landscape orientation so i should use autolayout.

Now the issue is how can i set different constrains for this moving view, for static view i set the different constrains which works fine for me as my below screenshot shows
[image]
[image]

As Above screenshot show the **(Y value as 371)** when i am trying to change it to **568** (which is my requirement) then i am not getting result as  above screenshot.

So question is there any way to use existing constrains for Moving objects without doing much changes to achieve the above result? Any Suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the change in the constraints themselves. Change the `constant` values of the constraints that need to change, and call `layoutIfNeeded` inside the animation block.

Example from my own code:

```
NSLayoutConstraint* con = self.v_verticalPositionConstraint;
con.constant -= 100;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    [self.v layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:nil];
```

In general, however, animation and autolayout are enemies, because they try to change a view's frame in two different ways. See the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout

Comment: Thanks it makes sense but i am confuse should i delete the Bottom space to superview constraints ? currently it has 0 constant value.